# In the Star Wars VCR board game, which die face has the Stormtrooper symbol?

Tags: star-wars-vcr

In *[Star Wars: The Interactive Video Board Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6810/star-wars-interactive-video-board-game)* (a.k.a. the VCR board game), the instructions say that the die has a Stormtrooper symbol on it:

> If you roll the Stormtrooper symbol, move the Stormtrooper forward **three** spaces.

Unfortunately, my used copy doesn't come with a die, so I'm not sure what the die looks like or which side has a Stormtrooper symbol. Can I use a regular d6? If so, which number should I use to indicate the Stormtrooper symbol.

<sub>And yes, I am playing this in 2017. The video is online, so I don't have to plug in a VCR player.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on evidence from a few photos online, it appears that the Stormtrooper symbol replaces the 1 on an standard die.

The [Board Game Geek gallery](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6810/star-wars-interactive-video-board-game) for this game includes a few pictures of the die.

This image shows that the Stormtrooper does not replace the 3 or 5...

[image: Star Wars VCR board game pieces]

... and this image shows that it does not replace the 2.

[image: Star Wars VCR board game pieces]

Another image from [VintageStarWars.net](http://vintagestarwars.net/vintage-1996-star-wars-the-interactive-video-board-game-vhs-darth-vader-footage/) shows that it does not replace the 6.

[image: Star Wars VCR board game pieces]

I was unable to locate a picture with either the 1 or 4 showing, but since a standard 6-sided die is oriented such that [opposing sides add to seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Arrangement) it seems reasonable to conclude that the Stormtrooper must replace the 1, since the 4 would be opposite the 3.  (It would also seem more logical to replace either the smallest or largest number, rather than one in the middle.)

Comment: I watched people playing the game on YouTube and their original die definitely had all the numbers except a 1 on it.